# deobfuscate javascript with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, reverse-engineering

Is there any way to deobfuscate some javascript code that produced with webpack 4 and is also splitChunked?

It's a little more than 1MB js code and I only need to understand a small portion of the  code, which is this function :

```
function l(e) {
            t.d(8, function(e) {
                for (var n = e.length, r = t.b(n), f = a(), c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                    var i = e.charCodeAt(c);
                    if (i > 127)
                        break;
                    f[r + c] = i
                }
                if (c !== n) {
                    0 !== c && (e = e.slice(c)),
                    r = t.c(r, n, n = c + 3 * e.length);
                    var d = a().subarray(r + c, r + n);
                    c += o(e, d).written
                }
                return u = c,
                r
            }(e), u);
            var n, r, f = (null !== i && i.buffer === t.e.buffer || (i = new Int32Array(t.e.buffer)),
            i), c = (n = f[2],
            r = f[3],
            d.decode(a().subarray(n, n + r))).slice();
            return t.a(f[2], 1 * f[3]),
            c
        }
```

I used chrome debugger and set some breakpoints and I was able to grasp what it's doing but I need to do the exact same thing in my project So I need a more readable code to do that.

Comment: Copy the code into your editor and start renaming variables to something more meaningful. btw, your snippet is relying on some dependencies: t.d, t.b, a, a().subarray, t.c, o, u, i, d.decode, t.a

Comment: I now that I can do that, but I wanted to know that is there any other way to unpack/deobfuscate/decode this whole code to something easier to read? something like a tool or software. BTW as I have figured out until now, t is a reference to a webassembly which have some functions called a,b,c,d,e and f.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do so, but I want to share some tips with you:

1. Replace all `','` with `', '\n'`
2. Review and correct the possible code breaks
3. Use a for loop to iterate between static value arrays and replace all the usages.
4. Change the encoding in case of language dependent breaks
5. Replace all `;` with `; \n` and correct possible code breaks
6. Know it is easier to rename functions and write comments for them.